# How do i make my card view adapt to different screen sizes

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-cardview

I want my card view to adjust its size to different screen sizes.Right now if i run my app on an emulator with a smaller screen the card view size remains the same.

here's my xml code.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:elevation="23dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/background_light"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
```